What has this figure to do with the Pythagorean theorem?

The legend tells that Pythagoras was looking at the square tiles of Samos' palace, waiting to be received by Polycrates, when he noticed that if one divides diagonally one of those squares, it turns out that the two halves are right triangles (whose area is half the area of the tile).
The area of a square whose side is the hypotenuse of one of those right triangles, is double the area of a square tile

this idea is pretty well shown in the picture below
$\hskip2in$
meanwhile at page ten of Mathematics and Its History - John Stillwell it's asked What has this figure to do with the Pythagorean theorem? There's also a note where it says dotted lines are a hint.


We have to conclude as previous, but I'm unable to fully appreciate the second picture. If we isolate only one tile is clear to me that the area of the square build on hypotenuse is the tile and the little square is the smaller leg. I'm missing how to ensure that the other square is related to the missing leg. In the end I think it's a matter of rearranging pieces and we get back to $a^2+b^2 =c^2$ but I'm missing a piece... well a tile!

Thank you for your help!

Here's an animated version I made years ago: https://newtonexcelbach.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/pythanim1a.gif

Where is that quote from?

@user3840170 From different internet resources 1, 2, 3. However I didn't check if the sources were reliable, it seemed like a nice way to introduce the problem!

There's actually a way to prove the theorem with this diagram that doesn't compare areas. Split one dotted square's height into two pieces with similar triangles. You get $\frac{a}{c}a+\frac{b}{c}b=c$. (You can do the same thing with an altitude in the right-angled triangle.)

What a great picture!  Pythagorean theorem easily proved without recourse to algebraic manipulation.  It'll always be in my toolbag.

I think this is the triangle you are looking for:

It shows where to look for the "missing leg".

For sure and here we can also appreciate the hint book gave. I think since the exercise is more visualization than formalization we shouldn’t worry about the fact that maybe triangles aren’t equal, should we?

@TurquoiseTilt Inside the large yellow triangle, at the bottom, is a smaller right triangle. By similar angles, it's the same as the trangle reflected up and to the left of it (whose corner is just off the left side of this picture). This gives that the small square's side is half the length of the large square's, and that pretty much gives everything else.

Actually, I take it back. I think you instead have to use the fact that it's a tiling to translate a square from another part of the diagram next to this one, which is how you can get that the small square is half the side length of the larger one.

COMMENT.-It seems to me that the sum of the two areas of blue squares is equal to the area of the red square.



It's a dissection. Consider the two smaller squares, chop the bits off that are outside the dotted square and place them inside the dotted square.
If you swap the smaller two triangles horizontally, the dotted square becomes a template for the tessellation.

The colouring here is misleading. The two yellow triangles are not necessarily equal. Rather, the top yellow triangle (outside the dots) equals the small orange one to its right (inside), and the bottom yellow triangle (inside) equals the small orange one to its right (outside). The text description is accurate but the colouring suggests that they should be matched by rotation rather than translation. It's unfortunate that the original demonstration chooses squares which are related by a ratio of exactly 1:2, when this ratio really doesn't matter for what's being demonstrated.

@kaya3; I thought of that, but OP seems to have picked the ratio on purpose, maybe to extract some other feature,  so I left it in.

This is just a combination of two other answers, but for the black triangle, $a^2$ (blue) plus $b^2$ (orange) equals $c^2$ (red).

It's a 1-2-$\sqrt{5}$ triangle (i.e. the second leg is twice as long as the first; we can see this from similar trangles), so $a^2$ equals the area of the triangle itself in this case.

Your triangles blue, black and yellow are those for which the result is verified really.

Sure, @mdfst13, that would be better. Actually, I can update the figure to express it that way.

The pattern can be made by repeating a shape made of a big square and a little square.
If you pick an easily identifiable point, such as the bottom-left point of a big square, you can find a square lattice of similar points. In the illustration, this grid is shown by the dotted horizontal and vertical lines. In a tiled floor, the square edges may fit the room edges, and the lattice may be harder to spot.
Each point on the lattice can be associated with the shape made from the small square and the big square, and also with a unit square of the lattice of similar points.
This pretty much hints that the two shapes ought to have the same area. It is not a neat proof because the pattern repeats indefinitely, and we haven't dealt with the edges. If you take any unit square, it always contains the same pieces of the big square and the little square. This hands you the dissection proof. All that remains is to spot that the edge of the unit square is the hypotenuse of the other two square sides.
PS: I do not believe the Pythagoras legend, but I do think the theorem was inspired by a regular tiling. The theorem was known in Babylon, which also used the tiling of big and little squares.
